# How do I use String.include? with forward slashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, rake, ruby-1.9.3

I'm using a rake task in Rails to look for strings to see if they have a now-decommissioned CDN in them:

```
if project.featured_thumbnail_url.include? "//cdn42.cloud.pizza"
  ...
end
```

This doesn't seem to work, neither does `\/\/cdn42.cloud.pizza`, both approaches fail with `syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end` errors. Am I doing it right?

Comment: "/" has no special meaning in string literals (or regular expressions). The **syntax error** is from other code than what is shown and has *nothing* to do with the string literal or later evaluation of `include?`. [Whatever the *real* syntax error happens to be is a "simple typographical error"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=syntax+error%2C+unexpected+keyword_end%2C+expecting+%24end) ..

Comment: Agreed.  Usually this is from an extra `end` placed in your code - or similarly, a missing `do` that should have begun a Ruby block.

Comment: [Post a minimally reproducible example (SSCCE)](http://sscce.org/). The mistake/issue will probably be found when eliminating other context.